# Microsoft 365 app - double icon/installation (2023)

Tags: software-installation, icons, .desktop, microsoft-office

I installed the desktop web app of Microsoft 365 on Ubuntu 22.04
(I believe it's a brand new option)

Somehow i must have done that twice, as i can see the 365 icon twice in the 'show applications' screen as well as in Settings/Application, but I cannot figure out how to remove one of the two installations/icons:

[image: screen shot of the application icons]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: in .local/share/applications/ there were two files with a similar name-structure (chrome-onhfoihkhodaeblmangmjjgfpfehnlkm-Default.desktop & chrome-ocdlmjhbenodhlknglojajgokahchlkk-Default.desktop). removing one from the application folder solved the problem.